# How do I send a message from a web site to my local machine?

Tags: asp.net

I want to send a string from a website to a local machine.

My local machine is connected into a network through a router.

Thanks You
email Id: manish.m.meshram@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Well, that largely depends on what the receiving computer needs to do with that string.
If you only need to notify the user of this, I would suggest the easier way is to go with the *net send* command.

Since you are wking in ASP.net, you can use the *Process* and *ProcessStartInfo* class to launch a command like

`net send YourPC "String to send"`

If you need to do something more sophisticated with the string message, you could for example print it in some sort of log file and then read it from the destination machine.

If you can give more information on your needs, we'll be probably able to help you better.

Luca

Comment: You would also need to ensure the Messenger service is running on both the web server and the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you poll the webapp for messages.

For instance, let the webapp have an URL that simply returns the timestamp of the most recent message, at `http://thesite.com/messages/MostRecentTimetamp.aspx`

The page should return the timestamp only, in an format you can parse, for instance:

`2009-08-29 14:00:00`

Then, on another URL, `http://thesite.com/messages/FromLastHour.aspx` display the list of messages for the last N hours (or other suitable time period). This page could return one message per line, with the message timestamp at the start of the line.

For instance:

```
2009-08-29 13:58:20 A message
2009-08-29 13:59:30 Here's a message
2009-08-29 14:00:00 Another message
```

On your local machine, create a program that as often as needed reads and parses `http://thesite.com/messages/MostRecentTimetamp.aspx`. If the program detects that the timestamp has changed, read `http://thesite.com/messages/FromLastHour.aspx` and process the new messages.

Adjust the timing according to your needs.

Or even better, have an URL: `http://thesite.com/messages/MoreRecentThan.aspx?timestamp=2009-08-29 13:50:00`.

That returns messages that are newer than the timestamp passed in. The program on your local machine should then pass the timestamp of the most recent message it has handled.

Of course, your web site has to keep track of outgoing messages in some sort of queue. You could use a database table for this. The web app can delete old messages from this table periodically.

If you want to get fancy, you could implement this as a SOAP web service. Or you could let the URLs return the data formatted as JSON.